# Is it possible to instruct a `Gtk::TreeView` to display a custom type?

Tags: c++11, gtkmm, gtkmm3

There is something I don't understand how to do with Gtkmm 3.

I have a custom business type that I have declared like this:

```
enum class Eurocents : int {};
```

I would like to render this type into a `Gtk::TreeView` which has a `Gtk::ListStore` as model. So I declare a `Gtk::TreeModelColumn<Eurocents>`, and add it to the model. I then `append_column` this model column to the `Gtk::TreeView` with an appropriate title.

I then `append_row` to the model and set the value corresponding to the column to `(Eurocents)100`.

The result I get is that the cell is displayed empty. Understandably so, because I would not expect Gtkmm to know how to render my arbitrary type.

I would like to instruct Gtkmm on how to render my type.

I already know how to display Glib types like `Glib::ustring` and formatting to `Glib::ustring` for display is possible, but it is not the subject of the question.

Is it possible to code columns that can display arbitrary types like this? And if so, how? What is required for sorting to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most common, and easiest way, is to use a cell_data_func callback. For instance, you can create your own instance of a Gtk::TreeView::Column (the view column), pack a cell renderer (or more) into your Gtk::TreeView::Column, append your Gtk::TreeView::Column to the TreeView with Gtk::TreeView::append_column(), and call set_cell_data_func() on your Gtk::TreeView::Column():
https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1TreeViewColumn.html#a3469e1adf42e5932ea123ec33e4ce4e1

You callback would then get the value(s) from the model and set the appropriate values of the properties of the renderer(s).

Here is an example that shows the use of set_cell_data_func(), as well as showing other stuff:
https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-treeview-examples.html.en#sec-editable-cells-example

This link should also be useful:
https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-treeview.html.en#treeview-cellrenderer-details

If you like, Gtk::TreeView::insert_column_with_data_func() makes this a little more concise: https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1TreeView.html#a595dcc0b503a7c1004c296b82c51ac54

As for the sorting, you should be able to just call set_sort_func() to specify how the column is sorted: https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1TreeSortable.html#a3a6454bd0a285324c71edb73e403cb1c

Then this regular sorting advice should apply: https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-treeview-sort.html.en

Comment: Thank you. Can you please elaborate on how appropriate sortability should be implemented?

Comment: What do you mean by "creating your own TreeView::Column"? Subclassing or instantiating?

Comment: @LaurentLARIZZA I mean an instance. I've edited the answer to clarify that.

Comment: @LaurentLARIZZA I've added some mentions of sorting.